# Can't load image after async call in ionic 2

Tags: image, asynchronous, ionic2

I'm trying to make a product grid, but I can't load its image after I make the asynchronous call to get the products from the server.

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let i of rows">
        <ion-col *ngFor="let product of products | slice:(i*2):(i+1)*2" width-50>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-img width="150" height="150" src="assets/img/eastereggs/placeholder.png"></ion-img>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                {{product.displayName}}
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                preço:{{product.price}} 
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col class="quantity">
                    <div class="add-product" [hidden]="product.quantity!=0">
                        <ion-icon name="add" item-right></ion-icon> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="set-quantity" [hidden]="product.quantity==0">
                        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft" item-right></ion-icon> 
                        {{product.quantity}}
                        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" item-right></ion-icon> 
                    </div>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

However, if load it without making waiting for the asynchronous call

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">
        <ion-col *ngFor="let product of [1,2,3,4,5,6] | slice:(i*2):(i+1)*2" width-50>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-img width="150" height="150" src="assets/img/eastereggs/placeholder.png"></ion-img>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                name
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                price 
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col class="quantity">
                    <div class="add-product" [hidden]="product.quantity!=0">
                        <ion-icon name="add" item-right></ion-icon> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="set-quantity" [hidden]="product.quantity==0">
                        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft" item-right></ion-icon> 
                        0
                        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" item-right></ion-icon> 
                    </div>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

Finally, to get the products I create the following promise

```
public getProducts(subcategoryId) {

    let qs = new URLSearchParams();
    qs.append('subcategoryId', subcategoryId);

    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.search = qs;


    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get(path, requestOptions)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

This data is then treated in another part, where I create the product array, that I don't think it's relevant, but I can post here if anyone thinks that's where the problem might be.

I've been looking for similar posts for a while, but most people were using the wrong path, but I don't think it's that, since I've already established that it works without the async call.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my guess is that the async call goes in timeout, then there is no image ressource loaded and the display fail. I had to manage that case and implemented a display case if the image value is 'null' or 'undefined' to cope with it.

In order to find out if this is a timeout causing the error, you can inspire yourself of  that class I use as a "Angular2 Service/Provider" to do all my call to the server. It manages the event of timeout. You'll need to use:     `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`,`import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith';`,`import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpService {

    private static readonly CLASS_TAG:string = "CustomHttpService";
    public static readonly ERROR_REQ_HTTP = "error_req_http"; 
    public static readonly TIMEOUT_ERROR_REQ_HTTP = "timeout_error_req_http"; 

    private static readonly TIMEOUT_DELAY = 3000;


    readonly url:string =  [your url string];

    constructor(public http:Http){}


    public sendRequest = (data):Observable<Response> | Observable<any> => {
        let headersToUse = new Headers();
        headersToUse.append("Content-type",'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        let options = { headers:headersToUse };

        return this.http.post(this.url, data, options).timeoutWith(CustomHttpService.TIMEOUT_DELAY,Observable.throw(new Error(CustomHttpService.TIMEOUT_ERROR_REQ_HTTP))).map(
            (res:Response)=>{
");
                return res;
            }
        )
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }

    private handleErrorObservable (error:Response|any){
        console.error(CustomHttpService.CLASS_TAG + " handlerErrorObservable: error " + error);

        let resError;
        if(error!= undefined && error.hasOwnProperty('message') && error['message']!=CustomHttpService.TIMEOUT_ERROR_REQ_HTTP && error['message']==CustomHttpService.ERROR_REQ_HTTP ){
            resError = error.message; 
        } else {
            resError = CustomHttpService.ERROR_REQ_HTTP;
        }
        return Observable.throw(resError);

    }



}
```